# Разбиение текста на предложения и запись каждого предложения в массив

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
for (int i = 0; i != strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if (((text[i] == '.') || (text[i] == '!') || (text[i] == '?')) && ((text[i + 1] != '.') || (text[i + 1] != '!') || (text[i + 1] != '?')))
        {

        }
    }
```

[image: Программа]

Как сделать разбивку текста на предложения и запись каждого предложения в массив?
Получается каждое предложение может заканчиваться на . ! ?, для проверки не идёт ли следом такой же знак, к примеру: ... или !! или !?, используем if

Comment: Для начала определитесь с тем, *что такое предложение*. И еще - у вас весь текст файла идет одной строкой?

Comment: Да без enter и /n.

Comment: enter - не символ.
Помимо \n могут быть и другие символы. Например \r .
Определитесь с тем, какие символы у вас составляют алфавит допустимых символов.
Какие из них являются признаком конца предложения?

Comment: @Gordory Предложение может заканчиваться на . ? !, я сделал проверку, посмотрите код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, требования стоят на использование библиотеки cstring и функций работы со строками как с массивом символов. 
Поэтому стоит смотреть:

1. [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/). Копирует определенное количество символов строки с определенного указателя.
2. [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/). Ищет указанный символ с определенного указателя.
3. [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/). Возвращает длину строки.

Пользуясь данными функциями можно соорудить алгоритм:

```
НачальныйИндекс = 0;
ИндексКонцаПредложения = НайтиВСтроке(СимволКонцаСтроки, НачальныйИндекс);
Пока (ИндексКонцаПредложения НЕ ПУСТО)
{
   ДлинаНайденногоПредложения = ИндексКонцаПредложения - НачальныйИндекс;
   КопироватьЧастьСтрокиВ(ПредложениеИзСпискаПредложений, НачальныйИндекс, ДлинаНайденногоПредложения);
   НачальныйИндекс = ИндексКонцаПриложения + 1;
   ИндексКонцаПредложения = НайтиВСтроке(СимволКонцаСтроки, НачальныйИндекс);       
}
Если (НачальныйИндекс < ДлинаСтроки - 1)
{
   ДлинаНайденногоПредложения = ДлинаСтроки - НачальныйИндекс;
   КопироватьЧастьСтрокиВ(ПредложениеИзСпискаПредложений, НачальныйИндекс, ДлинаНайденногоПредложения);
}
```

Разумеется алгоритм неточен в мелочах и варьируется в зависимости от реализации, но смысл я передал.

Остальное должно быть интуитивно понятно. Если нет - разбирайтесь и после спрашивайте.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сейчас прочитываю всю теорию, обязательно воспользуюсь вашим алгоритмом!

Answer (score 0):

Не могу угадать, насколько хорош должен быть алгоритм (реальная или учебная задача), но кроме завершающих знаков препинания нужно учтиывать еще следующие моменты (для русскоязчных текстов):

- новое предложение начинается с заглавной буквы, без этого знаки препинания не учитывать;
- Не рубить предложения по точкам в инициалах `B. В. Путин` , нормальные преддложения редко завершаютмя на `В.` (конечно, иногда будут ошибки). Кстати, изредка встречаются 2-буквенные иницалы, чаще иноязычные `Дж. Сорос`;
- списком проверять частотные сокращения с точкой `кв.` `т.е.` и пр. Cкорее всего, заглавная буква после них не начинает предложения, хотя тут будут ошибки достаточно часто.

Comment: Спасибо большое!